# Javascript array in array - first index is always overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with my JS function. For simplification, I want to fill an array (arr1) with n other arrays (arr2). In my loop I use a counter for the current postion in arr1 (cant use arr1.push for a reason). If I log all my arr2's in arr1 they are all the same, always the last one that was added. So I wrote a basic  script to test it. I always log the first element and incement the counter.
I'm new to JS, is there some huge misunderstanding I don't get?

```js
function test(){
 var arr1 = [];
 var arr2 = [];
 var counter=1;
 arr2[0]="first";
 arr2[1]="first";
 arr2[2]="first";
 arr1[0]=arr2;
  arr1[0].forEach(function(elem){console.log(elem);});
 for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
  arr2[0]=counter;
  arr2[1]=counter;
  arr2[2]=counter;
  arr1[counter]=arr2;
    
  arr1[0].forEach(function(elem){console.log(elem);});
  counter++;
 }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: You have to make a new `arr2` each time through the loop.

Comment: ... because `arr1[0] = arr2;` does not make a copy of `arr2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the spread operator.

```
arr1[0]=[...arr2];
arr1[counter]=[...arr2];
```

An array is a reference type, so you always refer to the base, you don't put a copy of it inside of arr1 but a reference to the arr2.

You want a copy of arr2 to be assigned to arr1.

You can do this by creating a new Array, or more modern the ... spread operator

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy said it, it just referenced the arr2 and doesn't create a copy.

So you need to

```
arr2=new Array();
```

at the beginning of the loop.